# Conditionals not Parsed in form

Tags: conditionals, module, forms

I am creating a form via module, that I wish to use for both insert and update. After the insert user has the option of going back to edit the values previously input. The issue that I encounter is with the update.

This function decides if insert or update

```
public function form()
{
    session_start();
    $tagdata     = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $variables   = array();
        $variables[] = $_SESSION['tags'];

        return self::buildForm('updateForm', $tagdata, $variables);

    }

    return self::buildForm('addDonation', $tagdata);
}
```

While this function handles the actual building of the form

```
public function buildForm($method, $tagdata, $variables = FALSE)
{
    $hidden_fields = array(
        'ACT' =>  $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id('Meal', $method)
    );

    if($variables != FALSE){

        $conditionals = $this->EE->TMPL->simple_conditionals($tagdata, $variables);
        $conditionals = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($conditionals, $variables);

        print_r($conditionals);

        $content = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_globals($this->EE->TMPL->final_template);

    }

    //Build an array with the form data
    $form_data = array(
        "id"            => $this->EE->TMPL->form_id,
        "class"         => $this->EE->TMPL->form_class,
        'hidden_fields' => $hidden_fields
    );

    $form = $this->EE->functions->form_declaration($form_data) . $content . "</form>";

    return $form;
}
```

The output is currently `{if FirstName !=` and {FirstName} within the conditional is not being parsed.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this more complex than needed. This should suffice:

```
if($variables != FALSE)
{
    $content = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_globals(
        $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata, $variables)//preps then runs parse_variables_row()    
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Printed out $content from your example. It is returning the conditional {if FirstName != ....nothing.
here is the markup from template `value="{if FirstName !=""} {FirstName}{/if}`

Comment: Don't just print it out - use it in a template. The template parser still needs to run through it for the conditionals to be parsed. At this point they are only _prepped_, not actually _parsed_.

Comment: I must not be using correctly, sorry lil new at this... Here is where I am attempting to put the content back into my form, and it's not being parsed here. `$form = $this->EE->functions->form_declaration($form_data) . $content . "</form>";`

Comment: That's correct - but just printing it out inside your add-on code won't yield what you expect. That final output still needs to be processed by the template parser, which happens when your front-end template which displays your form is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Guys over at Ellislabs straightened things out. Ended up being a simple variation on your suggestion. `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables` replaces `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row` , it does the prep work before calling `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row` -- If you would like to update your answer I'll be happy to accept.